# How to update a node after loadByProperties?

Tags: nodes, updating

I search for a node with field value client id and I need to update values. How do I do that in drupal 8?
I search with the following code

```
$profileNode = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
          ->getStorage('node')
          ->loadByProperties(['field_user_id' => $id]);
```

I get an array in response to this which corresponds to this. How do I update the node value with this?

Comment: This is a bit too broad of a question. There are many ways to update node values, which node values are you updating? The [Working with the Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api) documentation page should help you. Additionally api.drupal.org is a good resource to lookup the loadByProperties method return value (if you are not using an IDE such as PHPStorm or Visual Studio Code that would show you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you response array will contain one node as suggested by the variable name `$profileNode`

here is a suggestion to make it :

```
$profileNode = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node')
    ->loadByProperties(['field_user_id' => $id]);
// Get the node object.
$profileNodeObject = reset($profileNode);
if ($profileNodeObject) {
  // Make the changes we want : per example set the author to user 4.
  $profileNodeObject->setOwnerId(4);
  // Save the changes.
  $profileNodeObject->save();
}
```

Comment: Nice example, tested with application code, works well.